# SQL Server hash match when joining to view

Tags: sql, join, view, sql-server-2016, sql-execution-plan

I have a subquery, which always return 1500 rows, because of `TOP 1500` on the beginning. It gets left joined to a view, which returns 15mil rows if called outside any context. And in execution plan I'm ending up with hash match. In that case my query runs 2.5 mins.
I also tested this query on a dataset, for which view returns 7mil rows outside the context. And in that case, I have nested loops + index seek in execution plan, and query runs in 1 sec.
My indexes on the place on joining columns, and statistic is up to date.

The only solution I found out is to force `LEFT LOOP JOIN` to this view, but I'm looking for more elegant way to salve this problem. What are my potential options?

Comment: Without seeing your actual query, the table *and index* definitions, and the query plan (you can share this via https://pastetheplan.com) we cannot help. It's almost impossible to diagnose this kind of thing without proper info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you split the query?

Remove the view from the initial query. First filtered the rows (you are selecting only 1500 rows). Stored the result in a temporary table then join the table to the view.

The performance can be test easily like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEST;

SELECT ...
-- comment view columns
-- vw_
--
INTO #TEST
FROM ...
-- commenting the view 
--  leftj join vw_....
--     on ...

SELECT *
FROM #TEST
LEFT JOIN vw_
```

Also, some views can be [materialized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver16) using index and can improve performance, too.

Comment: this query is a one big ad-hoc query, which gets ran by users of the system regularly. I will consider to turn it to sp, to add a temp table

Comment: @yoma It will be better. I am sure. Rewrite it to SP and if it not perform well enough, post the body of the routine here.